# My toast does not work when the button is clicked and it force closes and restarts the main activity

Tags: android

```
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Double s1 = 0.0;
            s1 = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
            Double s2 = 0.0;
            s2 = Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());
            if (height.getText().length() == 0 || weight.getText().length() == 0 || (height.getText().length() == 0 && weight.getText().length() == 0)) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Enter the missing values";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                final Toast tost = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);

                tost.show();
            } else {
                Double bmi;
                bmi = s2 / (s1 * s1);
                it.putExtra("bmi_val", bmi);
                startActivity(it);
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Replace **context** with **YourActivityName.this**.

Comment: Thank you and i have another doubt my button works only when i double click it and for the second time it works normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Application Context for Toast, you have to use Activity

Comment: so i should replace context by means of bmicalc activity name?

Comment: you have to post the full code in order to answer this, if this one is inside an **Activity** class, you should change to `ABCActivity.this`; if it is inside **Fragment**, you should change to `getActivity()`